# MapReduce length 3 paths in directed graph

Tags: hadoop, graph, mapreduce

I am trying to solve an exercise but I still have not found the solution.

Design a MapReduce algorithm that, given as input a directed graph represented as a list of arcs, lists all pairs of nodes (x, y) such that there exists three arcs (x, a), (a, b) and (b, y). the length of the lists of the values received by the reducers should never be longer that the number of nodes in the graph. Please provide the pseudocode.

So long I found the paths with length 2 in the following way:

```
map (k, v): 
   write (k, (v, "out"))
   write (v, (k, "in"))

reduce(k ,list(v)):
   // write all pairs of nodes such that one has an arc exiting and the other has an arc entering
```

But from here on I cannot understand how to find the path with length 3, satisfying the property on the length of the lists.

Comment: If you manage to do so for length 2 so why not add them to the original arcs list with type 2 and execute another map reduce (to find length 2) but this time force the reduce to have type 1 and 2 which will be equal for one path with length 3?

Comment: @DavidWinder yes, I think this is the point, but how should I manage the keys? How do I do the grouping based in the keys in the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert in hadoop syntax but lets solve this theoretically.

Consider G=(V,E) - ARCS is ours E contains element such as (x,a), (a,b), (b,y)

You Found a way to extract all node with distance of 2. let call this set 2-LEN. In your short example it will contains (x,b) and (a,y).

Let create new set which define like this (pseudo code):

```
NEW_SET = new set
for each ((x,y) in ARCS)
     NEW_SET.add(x,y,1)
for each ((x,y) in 2-LEN)
     NEW_SET.add(x,y,2)
```

As you probably understand the third parameter is the distance. 
So now, for your example NEW_SET will contains: (x,a,1), (a,b,1), (b,y,1), (x,b,2), (a,y,2).

Now use the same logic in your 2-distance algorithm - mapreduce NEW_SET with:

```
map(k,v,d):
   write (k, (v, "out", d))
   write (v, (k, "in" , d))

reduce(k , list (v)):
   //write all pairs of nodes such that one has an 'in' and the other has an 'out' AND have different d
```

For the example after the map we will have the following:

- (x, (a,out,1))
- (a, (x,in,1))
- (a, (b,out,1))
- (b, (a,in,1))
- (b, (y,out,1))
- (y, (b,in,1))
- (x, (b,out,2))
- (b, (x,in,2))
- (a, (y,out,2))
- (y, (a,in,2))

So now you connect 2 distance node with 1 distance node resulting in all pairs with distance 3.

Notice that you will need to execute uniq on that set because you will get (x,y) twice - once from ((x,a),(a,y)) and one from ((x,b),(b,y))

As I mention, I am not expert on hadoop syntax but I believe there should be a way to implement that.

Comment: Thanks, I think that can be a good solution. I didn't think about of putting together arcs with distance 1 and arcs with distance 2.